# Instructive problems/exercises concerning CDFs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

I'm looking for instructive problems and exercises (resp. problems with an instructive solution!) surrounding the subject of cumulative distribution functions of random variables and measures.

Probability distributions are usually characterised by either their probability mass function (discrete space) or their probability density function (continuous space) which can both be seen as Radon-Nikodym derivative with respect to either the counting measure or the Lebesgue measure.
This representation (which is only unique almost everywhere) depends, however, on the absolute continuity with respect to the reference measure and there are (so called singular) distributions that are concentrated on a Lebesgue null set, but still assign zero mass to any point in that set. For these distributions neither a PMF nor a PDF can be defined. The Cantor distribution is the textbook example.

However, all the well-known and well-liked probability distributions I encountered in practice can be defined in terms of either their PMF or PDF. This sparks the question:

> What are good examples of "CDFs in action", e.g. problems that can be solved more easily or more elegantly in terms of CDFs rather than PDFs, or maybe cases where the CDF offers a specific insight.

And on a slightly different note:

> What are interesting problems directly concerned with the concept of CDFs?

The first concept that pops into my head is that of weak convergence which is for random variables usually defined in terms of CDFs. But I'm actually looking for way more basic applications that are suitable for a first course in probability.

---

Some context for those who are interested: The question recently came up when I tried to explain the significance of CDFs to a friend who is preparing for an exam in measure theory. He often asked questions like "why do I need that?" or "what is it good for?" which I have sometimes found challenging to answer. I usually resorted to the manifold applications in probability. But in this particular case I felt quite embarrassed not to come up with a better explanation.